# How does one stop a SWF Movie dynamically loaded using the Loader class using ActionScript 3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3

MovieClip(_loader.content).stop();
this.removeChild(_loader);
_loader.unload();
_loader = null;

I've been trying that, but it doesn't stop the movie.  The movie has an embedded voiceover
and that keeps running.  thank you.

Comment: How do you play the sound ? is it just a frame sound on the main timeline ?

Answer (score 1):

Flash 10 introduced unloadAndStop(); (_loader.unloadAndStop() if it's named _loader like in your example) and if you are using Flash 10 then you should use this.

But the original idea of what Adobe intended in AS3 for Flash 9 was that the loaded in swf would be self reliant, able to detect when it was removed and stop the sound from within itself. Use this inside the swf that is being loaded in, so that it can detect when it is removed from the stage, and therefore shut down it's own sound:

```
addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, swfWasRemoved);

function swfWasRemoved(event: Event) : void
{
  // inside this function shut down the sound that is inside the swf
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only remaining thing that is playing is the sound, use [`SoundMixer.stopAll()`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/flash/media/SoundMixer.html#stopAll()) to stop that as well.

Comment: I tried doing that. But as soon as another movie with a voice over begins, the old voiceover joins in as well.  :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the embedded voice over is set to stream.  If its on event, it will just keep playing until it's done regardless of the playhead of the swf.